# Import data to a publication list manually

Tags: marketing-cloud, publicationlist

Is there a way to populate a publication list manually through a CSV file? I can manually import data to a Data Extension but not to a Publication list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import into a subscriber's list. According to the documentation:

> The destination type. You can import the data into a subscriber list,
>   or data extension

You can view the documentation on how to import to lists [HERE](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/subscribers1/imports/)

Reference : [Import Activity](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/import_activity/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can import manually into a publication list. The process is same as importing into a standard list. The publication list will show up under 'My Lists'. Just select it and rest of the process is same from there

Comment: Yes, from Activities in Automation Studio.  There's no toolbar import for Publication Lists.