# Add subscribers to a publication list without sending an email (Marketing Cloud)

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, subscriber, publicationlist

So, we recently started using marketing cloud, and are looking to handle our newsletters campaign from there, we have a list of existing subscribers that we want to add to the Publication lists in Marketing cloud without sending a confirmation email, since these are existing subscribers, how can that be done?

Comment: If you have recently started using MC, you should consider whether a data extension based model is better for you than a list based one. TBH, I haven't implemented a single MC project using lists in the course of last 5 years. You can read about pros and cons here: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_list_versus_data_extension.htm&type=5

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import data to a publication list manually](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/179652/import-data-to-a-publication-list-manually)

Comment: Hi @zuzannamj, that article tells me how to import data to a subscriber list, is there a way to do something similar with publication lists? or maybe transform a subscriber list into a publication list?

Comment: Yes @LukasLunow, we are using both data extensions to get the subscribers directly from Sales Cloud, and publication lists to manage the subscription from the standard Subscription center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after giving it some thought, I've come to this solution:

I created an automation with three steps:

1. An SQL activity that will query the leads directly from our Sales cloud Org, and store the information I need in a Data extension, generating a csv file
2. A file transfer activity that will get that CSV file from the Safehouse to the ExactTarget Enhanced FTP
3. An import file activity that will take that csv from the FTP and import it onto the publication list.